# How can I handle two different repository in my flutter VS Code workspace folder?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, repository

My objective is to create a mobile / web app in Flutter with VS Code, I have uploaded the normal repository to GitHub, i made it private, now i want to upload the web folder in GitHub for GitHub hosting. This is public. My question is how exactly do i handle two different repositories in VS Code, I am unable to update or even upload just the web folder to GitHub. is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a workspace folder in VS Code that contains multiple repositories, VS Code will understand that fact. The Source Control sidebar will list each repository separately and allow you to perform source control management actions separately for each repository.

From [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_scm-providers):

> VS Code has support for handling multiple Source Control providers simultaneously. For example, you can open multiple Git repositories alongside your Azure DevOps Server local workspace and seamlessly work across your projects. To turn on the **Source Control Providers** view, select the overflow menu in the **Source Control** view (`Ctrl+Shift+G`), hover over Views, and make sure that **Source Control Repositories** is marked with a check. The Source Control Providers view shows the detected providers and repositories, and you can scope the display of your changes by selecting a specific provider.

If you want a subdirectory of a git repository to be excluded from that git repository and instead be its own git repository, then exclude it from the outer git repo by matching it in the outer git repo's `.gitignore`, and then turn that subdirectory into its own git repo using `git init` from inside that directory. Configure the git remote for each repository accordingly using `git remote add ...`.